# 2-dimensional array of 1s and 0s

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a random maze of `1`s and `0`s, and it does not have to be possible to solve. The program I am writing needs to be able to search through this maze and tell me whether not it is possible to get from the beginning to end. `0`s are fine to go through, but `1`s are like walls. Currently I am just trying to create the random array, and what I have so far compiles, but it returns this: `[[I@4ea20232`. So far I have this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SearchMaze{    
    public static void main(String [] args){    
        int n = 8;
        int m = 7;
        int[][] maze = new int[n][m];

        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                maze[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2);           

        System.out.println(maze);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get something like this:

```
1000000
1111100
0000001
1110111
1010101
1010101
0000110
1110000
```

I can't seem to find why something like this wouldn't work.

Comment: You're printing the reference to your array (by invoking its toString()); you'll need to iterate through the elements and print them individually (in much the same way you fill it).  You could also create a maze class which does this as its toString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `toString` of an array returns useless information. Using a list will not help much because it will print everything on one line with commas. Try to use nested loops to output the data.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.print('\n');
}
```

Comment: Could also replace the inner for-loop with an `Arrays.toString(maze[i]);`.

Comment: Tried to change your `System.out.print([i][j])` to `System.out.print(maze[i][j])` but edits have to be at least 6 characters long.

Comment: I fixed it. There was a missing word in the description to add as well.

Comment: I tried to implement this but it printed out a bunch of 0s in a straight line. How can I get it to print out and 8x7 block?

Comment: @Afatmunky Did you include `System.out.print('\n');`? This should output a new line.

Answer (score 2):

When you print an object like `System.out.println(a);`, you're really calling the `toString()` method of that object. Thus you're really calling `System.out.println(a.toString());`.

The `toString()` method of Arrays isn't particularly useful, so by doing `System.out.println(maze)` you're not going to see anything informative.

Fortunately, the `Arrays` class has helper methods that can reduce your problem to *a single line*. Try using:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(maze));
```

Given that your `maze` is 2d, you can use some replaceAll calls to format it like your post:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(maze)
        .replaceAll("],\\s\\[", "\n")
        .replaceAll(",\\s|]|\\[", "")
    );
```

Comment: When I put this into my code it ran it, but it printed out over 100 lines of 0s. D:

Answer (score 1):

Instead filling the maze with random values, you need to start will all `1`s and fill it with random paths e.g. going north or east for a given length.

Just like the loops you have you need to print them this way too.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to your problem, as it has already been answered, but how do you know where to begin and where to end?

Anyway, I came here to steer you towards the A* algorithm - it's a path finding algorithm that would be great for this type of application.

Comment: I'm just going step by step with it right now, but I am supposed to add in a value "S" and a value "E" (Start and End) that get placed somewhere randomly inside the maze.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to create an object for the maze:

```
public class Maze {

    public Maze(final int[][] maze) {
        this.maze = maze;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) {
                builder.append(maze[i][j]);
            }
            builder.append("\r\n");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private final int[][] maze;
}
```